# Search a text file for 2 strings and then write all the lines between the strings to another file

Tags: c#

Hi I have a report file that has a lot of data and I need to split it up but report name.

So each report is labeled “Report1” then there is some data and then “Report1End” then the next report label “Report2” for example starts this repeats till the end of the file.

I would like to be able to have method that I could pass the file location, Report1, and Report1End to and then have it create a new file with Report1’s data.

**Example of the file now**

> random junk
>
> Report1 
>   some stuff
>   some stuff
>   some stuff
>   some stuff
>   Report1End
>
> random junk
>
> Report2
>   some stuff
>   some stuff
>   some stuff
>   some stuff
>   Report2End
>
> random junk random junk

**Example of what I would like the output file to be**

> Report2
>   some stuff
>   some stuff
>   some stuff
>   some stuff
>   Report2End

Thanks for the help I used the example below and changed it a bit seems to work 100% for what I needed.

```
static IList<string> LinesBetween(string path, string start, string end)
{
    var lines = new List<string>();
    var foundStart = false;

    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path))
    {
        Match SMatch = Regex.Match(line, start, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (!foundStart && SMatch.Success)
        { foundStart = true; }

        if (foundStart)
        {
            Match EMatch = Regex.Match(line, end, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (EMatch.Success)
            { lines.Add(line); break; }
            else { lines.Add(line); }
        }
    }

    return lines;
}
```

Comment: I think the best way would be a 2 pass approach. Set two int variables such as beginningLineIndex, endingLineIndex, breaking after the 2nd, and then use the indexes to know what lines to output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static List<string> LinesBetween(string path, string start, string end)
{
    var lines = new List<string>();
    var foundStart = false;

    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path))
    {
        if (!foundStart && line == start)
            foundStart = true;

        if(foundStart)
            if (line == end) break;
            else lines.Add(line);
    }

    return lines;
}
```

Comment: Thanks used your example and just replaced the middle bit with reg ex

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a simple `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` combination:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputFile))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputFile))
    {
        string textLine;
        while ((textline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Check for your particular needs, and write
            // to the output file if applicable
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke function like--> Fn("abc.txt", "Report2", "Report2End");

```
       static string[] Fn(string path, string Start, string End) {

        string[] vc = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        int nStart= Array.IndexOf(vc,Start);
        int nEnd =Array.IndexOf(vc,End);
       return vc.Skip(nStart).Take((nEnd+1) - nStart).ToArray<string>();
         }
```